# Can anyone download Eclipse now?

Tags: eclipse

i cant download Eclipse. Is that Eclipse's problem?

This is the link
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages

Comment: It's a perfectly fine URL to use @StephenC. There are site issues going on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after a planned maintenance outage, the **eclipse.org website was** unfortunately **unreachable** up to now (2. August, 2021), but **is coming back up right now**. Please try again. The load balancing might require some reloading of the website and there might still be some issues until everything will be fully recovered, but downloading using a mirror should not be a problem.

See [eclipsestatus.io](https://www.eclipsestatus.io/):

> **Update** - Issue is coming from our main storage backend that requires a
> full resynch in order to be in working condition again. Given the data
> size, it will take about 13 hours. Thanks for your patience. We will
> keep you posted.
>
> Aug 1, 09:37 EDT

See also [@Eclipse_Status on Twitter](https://twitter.com/Eclipse_Status).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the eclipse server is working right now...