# an error occurred while installing eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

---

**I want to install eclipse for the first time on my device. i want to use it to develop java based application. but when i installed it i got the following error:**

[image: Error Message]

I've searched the eclipse forums but I didn't find the answer. If anyone has and knows how to solve it, I hope to be notified. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/68614982/6505250 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68617503/6505250

Answer (score 1):

they talked about this question in this community forum, maybe this help you, [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1069781/) or you should try with different jdks [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk16-downloads.html)